# Apache to connect through a proxy server

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

Currently I have reverse enabled as show below
Reverse Proxy

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

So any request that comes to my Apache with "/foo" will be forwarded to "http://foo.example.com/bar". But now what if my Apache can only access "foo.example.com" via a proxy 176.77.86.8:8888. How do I configure it.
using curl through my proxy is working as expected

```
curl -x http://176.77.86.8:8888 -L http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, ProxyRemote is the thing I was looking for

```
ProxyRemote http://foo.example.com http://176.77.86.8:8888
```